# WebClient DownloadFile method downloads damaged PDF files

Tags: c#, webclient

In my Windows application I am using WebClient DownloadFile method to download several PDF files from a server on local network.

Each file is a report that gets generated when its URL is called. Reports are of different sizes and take different periods of time to get generated.

My code loops through a list of URLs (about 400), and for each URL it calls DownloadFile method, and the corresponding report is generated and downloaded to local machine. URLs are definitely correct.

The problem is that almost each time the application is run, some of downloaded files are damaged, only 7KBs are downloaded (I think it’s for meta data), and Acrobat Reader gives me a message when I try to open the file:
“…it’s either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged…”

It’s not always the same files that get damaged, and when I re-run the application, those files often succeed, and some others might fail… it seems to be random and I can’t find out the criteria.

Note 1: I don’t want a file to start download until its precedence is completely downloaded, that’s why I am not using the asynchronous method.
Note 2: All files are Oracle reports and get generated by querying a database.
Note 3: No EXCEPTION is thrown in case of damaged files.

Here is my code :

```
using ( WebClient client  = new WebClient() )
{
    for(int i=0; i< URL_List.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
        client.DownloadFile( URL_List[i] , myLocalPath+fileName+".pdf" );
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
         // write exception message to error log...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the server, can you save to file what you're sending to the client to confirm that it's a client issue and not a server issue?

Comment: @MattHouser : do you mean that i should save generated report to server before calling DownloadFile method just to make sure that it was generated successfully?

Comment: Correct.  Isolate the problem.  Confirm the PDFs are actually being created properly. You'll waste time debugging the client if the problem is that damaged PDFs are being generated by the server.  Also, if you go to your PDF's URL using a standard web browser, does the file download correctly?

Comment: When i call the URL using browser it returns a correct PDF file. I don't know if generating a large number of reports sequentially is causing a problem on the server. Anyway, i have stated that damaged files are random! and re-running the application often works (damaged files are often replaced with correct ones). I will do as you told me as a test, and will feed back. Thank you so much, sir

Comment: Dear Matt, you where right. I remembered that when Oracle report fails it returns error message in an HTML page instead of PDF content, so i changed the extension of damaged files to HTML and they opened in browser. The content was a error message returned from Oracle Report... i haven't checked the problem yet, but at least now i know it's server side issue :) . Thank you so much for your help.